# case-sensitive filename created new issue in git repository

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, git-clone

I made a react project then I changed my CSS filename to lowercase and noticed I can't commit case sensitive only file name changes.

Then after some searching, I used `git config core.ignorecase false` then committed changes and pushed to my repository.

Now I have two separate files and after that when I clone my repository I only get an old file

how can I fix this issue?

[css files in my repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYbKT.png)

[css files in my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWx49.png)

Comment: You lied to Git; you now see the result. The `core.ignorecase` setting does not *control* whether your computer can create both a `README` file *and* a `readme` file in the same folder. Rather, it *tells Git* whether your computer can do that. Changing the setting means you're lying to Git. Git believes you when you say that your computer *can* do that. Don't change the setting unless you've changed how your computer behaves.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the "wrong" file from git storage :

```
git rm --cached -- BaDcAsEd.css
git commit
```

Once you've removed the wrong file from git storage, running `git checkout` should write the content you expect on disk.

It may not fix the name of the file name on disk though ; to fix that part, one trick is to do it in two steps, using a temporary name :

```
mv mYfIlE.css tmpfile
mv tmpfile myFile.css
```

---

With `core.ignorecase true`, if you need to change the casing in a file name in git, you may want to try one of the following options :

```
# option 1 : use git mv directly
git mv MyFiLe.css myFile.css

# option 2 : use git mv twice, with a tmp name
git mv MyFiLe.css tmpfile
git mv tmpfile myFile.css
```

(I don't have a case insensitive file system at hand to test which one works ...)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use git with a non case sensitive partition. Create a case sensitive partition in your computer to solve the problem of creation of files with same name with different case. Delete wrong file from a computer that have case sensitive file system. On linux file system is case sensitive. May I suspect your teams is working with different operative systems? Hope this little response can help you.